# A PostgreSQL trigger that moves a file on the filesystem

Tags: postgresql, triggers

Just getting started with PostgreSQL triggers, and am wondering if the following is possible:
I have a table in which a column stores filesystem paths to image files.  For example, each record's "img_path" field might contain something like "c:\images\a_great_image.jpg", or something like that.

When a database user changes the value in that field, is it possible that a postgresql trigger function could take care of (at least attempting) to "move" that file to its newly specified location?

Many thanks for the advice.

Comment: Yes you can do that, but keep in mind transactions are only possible when working with data within the database. That is to say the file is on the file system so if it fails for some reason you can't roll it back. Just something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. It's possible. Use plpython for example. Use this in trigger.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  move_file(old_path text, new_path text)
RETURNS boolean AS
$$
    import shutil
    try:
       shutil.move(old_path, new_path)
       return True
    except:
       return False
$$
  LANGUAGE 'plpythonu' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Thank you for this excellent example.  As JustBob noted above, the transaction will still be committed, even if the function returns false, correct?  Is there some way of rolling back based on the result of the trigger function?  Thank you!

Comment: You can raise exception when move_file returns false.